# Forgot Password

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, forgot-password

I am trying to create a web application to reset the password based on question/answer using `System.Web.Security` API.

I get an exception:

> DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007202f): A constraint violation
>   occurred" if user provide one bad answer to the question.

If I reset value of `attributeMapFailedPasswordAnswerCount` to not set the account becomes active again.

Account Lockout threshold in AD is set to 20 logon attempts.

I am novice on AD knowledge and  will be grateful if someone can guide me how to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: A web service to reset AD password based on a security question? Sounds like a really bad idea... Anyway, the exception is sort of useless without the code. If you post your code that threw this exception, it's more likely that someone may be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for giving me suggestion on potential security warning. I plan to extend it to cell phone and sending password reset on private email. But for now I have to surface out this web-service.

Comment: The problem is that the when attribute mapped to attributeMapFailedPasswordAnswerCount this field is set exception is thrown at all the functions with AD including login, change password or change security question/answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using ASP.NET? I don't really have any experience with it, nor do I have much experience with .NET in general (I'm still learning myself), but this was a really useful link providing examples of various Active Directory API's ([link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#46)). Including resetting a user password. Here is a link to the DirectoryEntry class, if you aren't sure how to set it up ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx)). Plus, just browsing through the [namespace documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) is very, very helpful ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx)). Probably the only thing I like about Microsoft is their good documentation.

I usually do something like this (in IronPython, so it will not translate directly to code you can use):

```
ou = System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ou=Users,dc=whatever,dc=something,dc=localetc")
search = System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(ou, "(samAccountName="+acc"+")", Array[str](["distinguishedName"]]))
result = search.FindAll() # note 1
if result.Count != 1:
    raise BadError
else:
    ent = System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(result[0].Properties["distinguishedName"][0])
    ent.Username = admin # note 2
    ent.Password = pwd
    ent.Invoke("SetPassword", Array[object](["newpassword!"]))
    ent.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0
    ent.CommitChanges()
```

Notes:

1. If this ever returns more than one result, you have issues.
2. this and the password are only necessary if the account running this does not have permission to change the user. I run these on an unprivelaged account so I have to include my admin credentials in the script (don't worry, they aren't hardcoded)

Oh and you're account lockout threshold is quite high. I would suggest 3-5, depending on the aptitude of your users.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the answer, I was able to figure out much more details with that. To add few more things which helped me were . The variables I was using to map to attribute, some of them were system variables and could not be used.

Hopefully, this might be useful for someone.

Second thing which I checked was that I searched local security policy and looked under Account Policies and account lockout policy. It should have defined values for all three variables. 

Anyways, thank you for your help and putting so much effort in the answer I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. If you have the time, read this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (it lists ALL attributes and their usability)